# Переход Codeigniter с версии php5.6 на php 7.2

Tags: php, codeigniter

Всем привет.

Нужно установить форум phpbb на сайт который написано на стареньком codeignither. Сайт работал отлично на версии php 5.6. Но для установки форума нужна версия 7.1. Меня настройки в хостинге сайт не открывается выдает следующую ошибку.

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()
```

ок, захожу в файл database.php и правлю

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

на

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

После этого появляется вообще ошибка что не может подключиться к Базе данных.

```
A Database Error Occurred
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в каком направлении копать?

Comment: перво наперво посмотреть отличия mysql_connect и mysqli_connect и отличия их работы

Comment: А что там в `Filename: core/Loader.php Line Number: 346` ?